# Unable to Programmatically Navigate Dynamic ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind PageViewModel.myCollectionOfThings, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:ThingViewModel>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<Button Name="TestButton" Tapped="TestButton_Tapped"/>
```

```
private void TestButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
PageViewModel.myCollectionOfThings.Add(newItem);
myListView.SelectedIndex++;
}
```

I'm trying to create a carousel control**.  Using the code above I can dynamically add an item to the end of the collection each time its selected index increases.  It works as one would expect except one problem.  Even though the UI is reflecting the new items added to the end of the ListView, if I iterate past the last index of the *original* collection size, the UI jumps back to the beginning of the list and the selected index becomes 0.  I've tried many variations of the above code and tried different collection types.  I've also tried re-assigning the ListView's ItemSource each iteration which didn't do anything.  Any help would be appreciated.

**I know there's something called Carousel in the UWP Community Toolkit but it isn't actually a carousel.  A carousel can scroll endlessly as its collection will loop, which that control does not do.

Comment: Some clues.  When I reach past the index of the original collection size, it jumps back to the start and becomes SelectedIndex 0.  I used a VisualTreeHelper method to monitor the children in the ListView.  It seems that each time I add an item, the child count does not increase.  It is only after this "reset to 0" takes place, then the child count reflects the proper number of items.   So even though the collection count is changing, and the myListView.Items.Count() is changing, the child count does not update until the ListView is set to an index value it though was out of range.

Comment: I created a sample project. it's working as expected. Can you provide the entire class? so that I can try to solve your issue OR use the Windows AppStudio Carousel control.

Comment: Did you use List with INotifyPropertyChanged or ObservableCollection as ItemSource?

Comment: Yes.  And the UI reflects the changes.

Comment: What did you use `List` or `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: List<T>, Stack, LinkedList, and ObservableCollection.  INotify with all except the latter.  As I said, the UI is updating.  New items are being added to the end and it is visually reflecting this.  But when I get past what used to be the last item it jumps back to the first item and SelectedIndex becomes 0.

Comment: If you use `List with INotifyPropertyChanged` then this might happen because after calling `PropertyChangedEventHandler` the whole list will bind again. Try using ObservableCollection you don't need to use  INotifyPropertyChanged in this. If this doesn't work then I think you are making a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: I have been mostly using ObservableCollection during all of this.

Comment: Thanks for testing the sample project.  It led me to do the same and had the same results as you--I couldn't repro it.  So I went back to my real project and figured it out.  The new item I was adding to the end of the collection was actually a reference to the first item in the collection, which explains the behavior.  At the time I believed I was creating a new instance but apparently I was not.  I was however correct in noticing the child count wasn't updating which is odd.  Anyway I'll try out the other Carousel control thanks again sorry for the goose chase.

Comment: Glad you have figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Carousel that can scroll endlessly then take a look at the [Carousel](https://github.com/wasteam/waslibs#carousel) control in the [Windows AppStudio NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAppStudio.Uwp). Download [Windows App Studio UWP Samples](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/windows-app-studio-uwp-samples/9nblggh4r0w1) to learn about the control.

Here an image of this Carousel Control[image]

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about that one!  I'll try it out.  I feel like I shouldn't mark this as an answer though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the listview is rebinding with binding source when the collection is changed. Try to re-set the index manually after adding the item.

```
int currentIndex = myListView.SelectedIndex;
PageViewModel.myCollectionOfThings.Add(newItem);
myListView.SelectedIndex = currentIndex++;
// If above doesn't work try setting selectedItem property to newItem.
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not it.

Comment: Just to clarify I did try these suggestions and it makes sense that would be the issue but it wasn't.